# Best way to pause/resume CALayer animation

Tags: iphone, sdk, resume

I have seen code to pause/resume CALayer animations, like so:

[To Pause]

```
CALayer *layer = object.icon.layer;
CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
layer.speed = 0.0;
layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
```

[To Resume]

```
CALayer *layer = object.icon.layer;
CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer timeOffset];
layer.speed = 1.0;
layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
layer.beginTime = 0.0;
CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
```

And this works just fine. The problem is if a new ViewController is pushed onto the ViewController stack, or the App enters the background and then comes back the CALayer animations immediately snap to their end positions!

What is a good way to handle effective pause/unpause UIView animations? In which I can minimize the application and bring it back, or change the active ViewController without loosing the animation!

Answer (score 0):

I think on suspend you need to remember the mediaTime of your root layer, and restore that value once your app resumes... Otherwise the time will jump by he amount of time that has passed while your app was suspended.